# Div centering and max width issues

Tags: html, css

A while back I had the `following` code:

**HTML:**

```
 <div align="center">
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    background-image: image here;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    max-width: 1920px;
}
```

Now I'm typing this in my sleep at night which suggests that there were no errors in the actual program because I kinda just rewrote this... Anyways, once I saved and refreshed the site, the div wasn't displaying in the center if I'd had zoomed out. Weird right?

Now when I took out the max width and simply changed the first value of background-size to 1920px, it started working! What I want is a div that changes according to size although doesn't grow bigger than `1920px` and stays in the `center`. What do I ;)?

Comment: Try use `background-size: cover or contain`

Comment: Tried adding `margin: auto`? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3uxe/2/embedded/result/) [fullscreen result](http://jsfiddle.net/K3uxe/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%;

Answer (score 1):

The align property has been removed (it was deprecated some time ago).  Use CSS for centering:

http://jsfiddle.net/K3uxe/4/

```
<div>
     Divje
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    background-color: red;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    max-width: /* your width */;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto; /* this is your centering for block elements */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this jquery event and function
jquery :

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);


function resizeFrame()
{
var newHeight = $(window).height();
var newWidth = $(window).width();
$('.DIV_CLASS_').height(newHeight);
$('.DIV_CLASS').width(newWidth);
}
```

May Be Helpfull

Comment: JavaScript solutions for CSS problems are frowned on unless a pure CSS solution is not possible.